# CMake 3.4.3 Can't find CUDA on windows

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

I am trying to build something with CMake (it has to be an older version because of the project) and when I run it I get this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:617 (message):
  Specify CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  libethash-cuda/CMakeLists.txt:3 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I have looked everywhere online but I only find solutions for Linux.

Comment: ***CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR*** Looks like a `CMake` variable. You would set that in cmake-gui. Or via the command line argument -D when launching cmake from a command prompt setup with the environment for your compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm Or inside the `CMakeLists.txt` of the project. ;)

Comment: I tend to not force any path inside a `CMakeLists.txt` although for me I build on many machines (use git or svn to hold the code) and even multiple compilers for the same source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, my CMake (v3.7.0) found the toolkit automatically. It's located in:

`C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0`

In general, I've found on Windows it has difficulty finding the SDK which is in:

`C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v8.0`

To set ***CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR*** in CMake on windows, open up cmake-gui, run "configure" once then go to "advanced:"

[image]

Scroll down until you see ***CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR***:

And set it to your CUDA toolkit directory (which is probably `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0` if you're using CUDA version 8.0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone —recursive https://github.com/Danko-Lab/Rgtsvm.git
cd Rgtsvm
git submodule init
git submodule update

mkdir build
cd build

cmake .. -G”Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64" -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DLIBR_EXECUTABLE=”C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/140/R_SERVER/bin/R.exe” -DR_LIB=ON -DGPU_COMPUTE_VER=52
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

does it for Win10, where

- -G”Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" what your VS version is
- -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64" where your CUDA version is installed
- -DGPU_COMPUTE_VER=52 [choose your GPU architecture](https://arnon.dk/matching-sm-architectures-arch-and-gencode-for-various-nvidia-cards/)